# Docker - Windows Containers development on Windows 2019 / 2016 VM

Tags: docker, containers, windows-server-2016, windows-container, windows-server-2019

I am looking to do some Windows Container  based development specifically for .NET Framwework 4.x apps (not  .NET Core). 
To this end - I am in a scenario where in getting Windows 10 box / VM is out of question for the immediate future. I have only the possibility of getting Windows 2016 VM or Windows 2019 VM with nested Hyper-V.

My questions is this  - would I still be able to Windows container based development without any issues on a Windows 2019 / Windows 2016 VM ?
Is there any specific guidance on Docker installation and usage  for this development purpose ?

Comment: Have you check the system requirements?  > https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#system-requirements

Comment: @abestrad yes. That link is essentially Docker desktop for Win 10. My question is Docker based development on Windows 2016/2019 VM.

Comment: The setup is slightly different, but yes it works fine: https://hub.docker.com/editions/enterprise/docker-ee-server-windows. One thing to keep in mind, you need to use the same OS version to build the container as the OS you intended to deploy it to, so if you build on 2019 you have to deploy to 2019 as well